# Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method mu.b

Tags: java, android, face-detection

When I start app and click button, I'm getting an error.I want make take photo and detect face after Automatically add on glass.

> Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method mu.b

Also

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappin‌

Here is my gradle

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear... What is `mu.b`?

Comment: i dont know cricket-007

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: @cricket_007 My best guess would be obfuscated class and method from a non-public part of the API.

Comment: Do you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

this seem to be a proguard issue.

Try adding to your proguard-project.txt:

```
keep class com.google.android.chimera.** { *; }
dontwarn com.google.android.chimera.**
```